# Displaying text on the screen with a delay (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hello everyone I recently started development in Android Studio and ran into a problem. I am developing a text novel by analogy with lifeLine. The bottom line is that the text of the story is displayed on the screen with a slight delay. I want the gameplay to be like a chat in a messenger. When the text from the array is fully displayed on the screen, from 2 to 5 buttons with the choice of action should be displayed.

Now I will describe the problem. To display the text, I use the ListView component. If I add a delay of 1 second to the loop, then the text will not be displayed sequentially, but will be displayed completely. And I would like the text to be displayed sequentially with a delay of 1 second. I tried using a handler and it helped. However, when I want to display the buttons after the loop ends, it doesn't work and the button is displayed immediately. I understand why this is happening.

But I have a question - is it possible to abandon the use of multithreading? What is the best way to implement my idea?

Main Class:

```
public class GameMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);

        ListView mainList = findViewById(R.id.list_of_text);
        //NewGame newGame = new NewGame();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

        String[] listText = {
                "Text1",
                "Text2",
                "Text3",
        };

        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        SetTextOnDisplay textOnDisplay = new SetTextOnDisplay();
        textOnDisplay.displayTextSequentially(listText, adapter);

        Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_main_1);
        button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

The class for displaying text:

```
public class SetTextOnDisplay extends Thread {
    public void displayTextSequentially(final String[] listText, final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        int delay = 500;

        for (int i = 0; i < listText.length; i++) {
            final int index = i;
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.add(listText[index]);
                    if (index == listText.length) {
                        //Button button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_main_1);
                        //button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }, delay * i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in order to display the content every x seconds you'll have to run the update asynchronously. As you'll ask the user to make a choice you'll have to then display different branch of your story. How did you plan to manage that part?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I thought that Android Studio has built-in components that allow me to implement my idea without using asynchronous methods. Apparently, this is not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using handler like this:

```
public class GameMain extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mainList;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private String[] listText;
    private int currentIndex = 0;
    private Button button1;

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_main);

        mainList = findViewById(R.id.list_of_text);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listText = new String[] {
            "Text1",
            "Text2",
            "Text3",
        };

        mainList.setAdapter(adapter);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.button_main_1);
        button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        displayTextWithDelay();
    }

    private void displayTextWithDelay() {
        if (currentIndex < listText.length) {
            adapter.add(listText[currentIndex]);
            currentIndex++;

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    displayTextWithDelay();
                }
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            button1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```